# SQL: What if user don't define any datatype to attributes or keep all the datatypes as varchar?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite, relational-database

I am starting out with SQL. I am learning it using sqlit database.

While practicing create table i noticed that even if i don't define any datatype a table is created and I am able to execute all insert and select command.

Also if i define all the datatypes to varchar it works well.

Please tell me is this the right way?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL standard defines field types, there are different operations available for each type, so no, setting all to varchar is not the right way.

On the other hand, SQLite uses a different type system, in effect it's similar to dynamically typed languages, where the type is associated with the values, not the variables.  In SQLite you can store an integer in a field declared as a varchar, and it will not only work, but remember that it was an integer and operate as an integer.

For an embedded library, it's a very practical system but deviates from the standard, so if you want to learn "SQL", then it's better not to rely on SQLite's peculiarities.